# Avoid repetition of formulas in SELECT

Tags: sql, teradata

Let's say I have the following:

```
SELECT 

    users_aggregate_data.treatment,

    SUM(users_aggregate_data.GS_Oct_Dec),
    AVG(users_aggregate_data.items_sold_Oct_Dec),
    --  .. and a few other such as std_deviation, ..

    SUM(users_aggregate_data.GS_Jan_Mar),
    AVG(users_aggregate_data.items_sold_Jan_Mar)
    --  .. and a few other such as std_deviation, ..

FROM users_aggregate_data
```

In `users_aggregate_date` I have painfully aggregated sales data by customer and by time span.

I was wondering if there's a way to avoid all that boilerplate code above.

Comment: Where's the boilerplate? All the aggregations you've shown are completely different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases for table names (this will increase readability), but you have to specify the column names (if you don't want to use just `SELECT *`)

```
SELECT d.treatment,
       SUM(d.GS_Oct_Dec),
       AVG(d.items_sold_Oct_Dec),
   --  .. and a few other such as std_deviation, ..
       SUM(d.GS_Jan_Mar),
       AVG(d.items_sold_Jan_Mar)
   --  .. and a few other such as std_deviation, ..
  FROM users_aggregate_data d
```

About alias you can read more here: [SQL ALIAS Tutorial](http://usefulfreetips.com/Teradata-SQL-Tutorial/sql-alias-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks. I understand aliases. I was wondering if there was a way to avoid all those repetitions of column names....

Comment: not really, you could think about a way to generate your script dynamically, but at the end the column names have to be in the SQL code executed. Or you can aggregate the data in a different way, having the period in a column and then a column for the sum, then one for avg, one for std and so on

Comment: Thanks. You gave me an idea on the second point. About dynamically generating a script, are there tools out there? Thanks again

Comment: not sure about tools, I usually wrote procedure for that, something like [this](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1141_111A/ch03.105.042.html)